# Sort integer in array in Objective-C

Tags: arrays, sorting, nsarray

I have this array with 10 different numbers:

```
int number[9];
```

It gets filled by random function:

```
for(i=0; i<10; i++)
   number[i] = arc4random() % 100;
```

Every number can only be taken once.

Now my problem - I want to sort them by value like this:

```
number[0] == 2
number[1] == 5
number[2] == 16
number[3] == 22
number[4] == 31
number[5] == 43
number[6] == 66
number[7] == 67
number[8] == 87
number[9] == 93
```

How to do this?

Sorry guys, I am using Xcode. I need a NSArray.
So I need to start from beginning:

```
NSArray Zahl[9];  ????????
```

Comment: This is a C question.  If it were an Objective-C question, we'd have an `NSArray` full of `NSNumber` objects.

Comment: you don´t have an Array with 10 numbers, you have an Array with 9 numbers

Comment: Sorry guys, I am using Xcode. I need a NSArray